# How to debug django with VSCode?

Tags: django, visual-studio-code

Default configuration kind of does not work:

```
{
    "name": "Django",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "stopOnEntry": false,
    "pythonPath": "${config.python.pythonPath}",
    "program": "${workspaceRoot}/manage.py",
    "console":"externalTerminal",
    "args": [
        "runserver"
    ],
    "debugOptions": [
        "WaitOnAbnormalExit",
        "WaitOnNormalExit",
        "DjangoDebugging"
    ]
},
```

Comment: Please provide more information on what you have tried, what you are experiencing. There's not enough information here to help you. Also, please raise this issue on github (I'll look into this form there, it easier https://github.com/DonJayamanne/pythonVSCode/issues/new)

Comment: Thanks for replying. I had kind of edited debugOptions manually, and that kind of broke things up. Lesson learnt? Don't mess with debugOptions if you're not totally sure about what you're doing AND you know that your debugging method supports what you're doing.